# Issue in retrieving images from mysql databse to store on local disk using java

Tags: java, mysql, ubuntu-14.04

I Stored images to mysql database using java after converting it to `bytes[]` and then `Blob`. Image format is `png`
Trying to retrieve images from mysql  database and converting it to image file to save on local disk.

iterating mysql Resultset as:

```
while(rs.next())
{
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(rs.getBytes("image"));

Iterator<?> readers = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("png");
ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) readers.next();
Object source = bis; 

ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(source); 
reader.setInput(iis, true);
ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();

Image image= reader.read(0, param);
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(image1.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

Graphics2D g2 = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
g2.drawImage(image, null, null);

File imageFile = new File(rs.getInt("id")+".png");
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", imageFile);
}
```

but it giving me error:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: I/O error reading PNG header!
```

it causes due to:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Bad PNG signature!
```

i am new to java. I googled it but not find any satisfactory solution.
can anyone help me to solve it or any other better solution to retrieve images from database and store in local disk???

Comment: What type is the column `image`? Is it a blob or anything else?

Comment: And why do you convert the read data to a BufferedImage? Wouldn't it be enough to save it as a file in the disk, just "as is"?

Comment: Which line is giving you the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution. issue was in my code. here is correct code that i am using to fetch images from database and to store as image file

```
sql="select * from image_data where image_id="+image_id;        
        rs = this.runSimpleQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) 
        {
            Blob image_blob=rs.getBlob("image_100x100");
            int blobLength = (int) image_blob.length(); 
            byte[] blobAsBytes = image_blob.getBytes(1, blobLength); 
            InputStream in=new ByteArrayInputStream( blobAsBytes );
            BufferedImage image_bf = ImageIO.read(in); 
            ImageIO.write(image_bf, "PNG", new File(folder_path+"/"+rs.getString("name"))); 
        }
```